# spring boot conflict with spring mvc for register applicationEventMulticaster twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using spring 4.2.5 and spring boot 1.3.3，both of them register 
applicationEventMulticaster for event handling, the only way I figured out is to override initApplicationEventMulticaster and destroy applicationEventMulticaster after calling initApplicationEventMulticaster on super, which is not elegant. The reason why I have to use spring mvc context is that I had a lot Autowired staff managed by the context.

here's the entry code of my Shell Project using spring boot and spring mvc

`ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Shell.class).contextClass(RoseShellContext.class).web(false).run(args);`

`RoseShellContext extends RoseAppContext extends AbstractXmlApplicationContext`

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: There should be only a single one, if there are multiple you are doing things in a wrong way.

Comment: I think it's better for spring boot to have a check whether the beanfactory has already had any multicaster registered as applicationEventMulticaster, in that case spring boot could use that one instead of creating a new one.

Comment: As stated it already does, if you have issues with that, you must be doing something in a wrong way.